# add to cart not working in magento with configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, cart, custom-options, addtocart

I'm working on **configurable product** which contain drop down as Custom , Small, Medium, Large etc i want to add certain **text box** when user click Custom option which I had achieved using CSS and jQuery functionality is working well with different drop down but add to ca rt is not working with Custom option 
I'm attaching code to achieve goal can

```
<?php $_option = $this->getOption(); ?>
<dt><div class="test"><label<?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo  $this->escapeHtml($_option->getTitle()) ?></label>
    <?php echo $this->getFormatedPrice() ?></div></dt>
<dd<?php if ($_option->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
    <div class="test">
    <?php if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_FIELD): ?>
        <input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" id="options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text" class="input-text<?php echo $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?> <?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ? ' validate-length maximum-length-'.$_option->getMaxCharacters() : '' ?> product-custom-option" name="options[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDefaultValue()) ?>" />

            <?php $img= Mage::getModel('newdashboard/newdashboard')->getCollection()->getFirstItem();
                $img->getFilename();
             ?>
        <img width = '40' height = '40'src = "<?php echo '/media/' . DS . $img->getFilename()?>"/>
    <?php elseif ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_AREA): ?>
        <textarea id="options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="<?php echo $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?> <?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ? ' validate-length maximum-length-'.$_option->getMaxCharacters() : '' ?> product-custom-option" name="options[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" rows="5" cols="25"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDefaultValue()) ?></textarea>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($_option->getMaxCharacters()): ?>
        <p class="note"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Maximum number of characters:')?> <strong><?php echo $_option->getMaxCharacters() ?></strong></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</dd>


<style>
    .test{
        display:none;
    }
    .product-options dd select {
        width: 150px !important;
    }
    .product-options dd input.input-text{
        width: 160px !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
jQuery('.super-attribute-select').change(function (index)
        {
            var c=jQuery(this).children(':selected').text();
            if( c== "Custom" || c== "custom"){
                jQuery('.product-custom-option').show();
                jQuery( "input" ).addClass( "required-entry" );
                jQuery('.test').show();
        }  
       else{
                jQuery('.product-custom-option').hide();
                jQuery( "input" ).removeClass( "required-entry" );
                jQuery('.test').hide();
        }
});
</script>
```

does anyone has solution for this issue